Issue with Mui Data Table Pagination
I am currently working on a project where I take data from the CoinMarketCap API and display in a MUI Data Table(more exactly StickyHeader Data Table) and I keep having problems with the color of the text. I am trying to make the text and icons color from black to white(since my background is black), and I keep having problems with it.
I have tried giving it a class and giving that class a color: #fff atribute but doesn't work.
I have tried putting it directly in the code through style={{color: #fff}}.
I have tried doing it through makeStyles().
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiPaginationItem-root': {
      color: 'white',
    },
  },
});


try using createTheme from '@mui/material/styles'
Here is the code. use in theme.tsx file


import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const Theme = createTheme({
  components: {
      MuiPaginationItem:{
         styleOverrides: {
          root: {
             color:"white"
            }
           }
       }
    }
  })




Still doesn't work sadly.
